# How do I make my two side by side divs the same height?

Tags: html, css

[My code @ JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LQ43P/)

```
code that is needed
for linking JSFiddle
links
I don't understand why I need
this.
```

[An image of the two divs, their the gray boxes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVYrh.jpg)

How can I make these two divs the same height? I don't want to do the padding-bottom: px; and margin-bottom: -px; It seems really like cheating and just rigged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:table` and `display:table-cell`:

```
#who-is {
    width: auto;
    display: table;
}

#left {
    width: 40%;
    padding: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #CCC;
    display: table-cell;
}

#left h1 {
    font-size: 72px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#right {
    width: 40%;
    padding: 5%;
    background: #eee;
    display: table-cell;
}

#right p {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LQ43P/2/)